# skip empty cells in loop

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below macro that should highlight cells in sheet2 different from cells in sheet1. It's working well but I have a problem with it highlighting blank cell:

```
Private Sub Compare()

Dim shtARng As Range, cell As Range

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set shtARng = .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)) 
End With

With Worksheets("Sheet2") 
For Each cell In .Range("C2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp))
    If shtARng.Find(What:=cell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False) Is Nothing Then cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
Next cell
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Couldn't you not just use conditional formatting to achieve the same result more efficiently?

Comment: Probably, I'm new to this... My goal was to flag the different values and copy them to another sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub Compare()
Dim shtARng As Range, cell As Range

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set shtARng = .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    End With

    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        For Each cell In .Range("C2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp))
            'Only Proceed If The Length Of The Cell Is Bigger Than Zero
            If Len(cell) > 0 Then
                If shtARng.Find(What:=cell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False) Is Nothing Then cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            End If
        Next cell
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: the "If Len(cell) > 0 Then" seemed to worked for all empty cells. This is mind boggling.

Comment: mind boggling indeed. Have you checked that the first empty cell is really empty or if it just appears to be ;)

Comment: Yeah, it's empty :)

Answer (score 1):

Use IsEmpty to check if the cell is empty. If it is not empty then do your highlighting, otherwise loop on to the next cell.

```
For Each cell In .Range("C2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp))
    If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
        If shtARng.Find(What:=cell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False) Is Nothing Then 
             cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
     End If
Next cell
```

Comment: Now it seems to be highlighting only the first blank cell

Comment: Did you do if not?

Comment: Yes, I copied the part you added. It seems to be working for all blank cells except the first one in the row